# Global actions and clickjack protection

Tags: visualforce, clickjacking

Clickjack protection protects your SF org by blocking pages served from a different domain.

Now, I see an issue with you mix it with VisualForce custom global actions.

**Repro steps**

- Create the world's simplest VF page:

`<apex:page>`
    `<h1>Hello World</h1>`
`</apex:page>`

- Create a new Global Action, and make it of type "Custom Visualforce", and point it to your VF page.
- Add it to the page layout of, say, Account.
- Turn clickjack protection on
- Navigate to any account
- Try to display the quick action
- This should generate an error message

I think this is caused because the Global Action is served from within an iframe. The main page is in the `salesforce.com` domain, while the iframe will point to `visual.force.com` domain. Clickjack will dutifully protect you from the dangers of the foreign VF page.

However, this is terribly broken. It's a VF page in my own org! It so happens that Salesforce likes to serve it from a different domain.

I've tried hiding the headers with `showHeader="false"`, but now we have clickjack protection with VF pages with no header, so it doesn't cover me in all circumstances (this is in the context of a managed package, so our customers have different CJ settings).

Telling our customers to disable clickjacking is not always an option. Ironically, [SF recommends not serving pages from within iframes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_vf_clickjack_with_headers_disabled.htm), but this is not under our control. The SF framework for Global Actions uses iframes.

Has anyone experienced similar issues? What have you done to fix it?